# Dupliverts rotation not working

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to create a spiked sphere using dupliverts, followed all the steps (spike facing Y axis, parent-child, checking rotation) and it still won't work. I tried different axes and still no luck. The spikes are not pointing towards the normals. Any help please.

[image: dupliverts]

Answer (score 3):

On the Object Data tab, you need to go to Relations Extras (Just below Duplication) and under the Tracking Axes pick Axis: +Z and Up Axis: Z.

Comment: @Beatrice My pleasure. Could you click the checkmark on the side, under the vote buttons, to mark the answer as accepted? That way, when someone with the same problem comes to the site, they'll be able to immediately see that it has an answer that works. You can also vote up my answer, if you didn't do it already, to mark it as helpful. Thank you.